# mySQL - how to convert "condensed in 1 column data" to standard table with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, database, forms

I have a form (using a tool called Easy Forms) that writes data from form entries into a mysql database. However, the data is stored in a strange way, the likes of csv format.
1 entry = 1 line in the table, but all the information the user submits is stored in one single column named "data", like this:

{"text_734077":"John","text_442391":"Doe","text_485406":"+4101020304","email_876265":"john.doe@email.com","textarea_508384": etc ...

[image: situation as of today]

I believe "text_734077" and the other similar values are the names/types of the fields in the form.

I need to use this data with another tool, but I cannot do anything with this.
I did not create this database and form, but I will be managing it in the future.
How can I transform this into a standard table with real columns (name, email, phone, ID, etc) within mysql? The Easy Forms tool can display this data as a table so I should be able to do it as well:

[image: what I would like]

But this would be perfectly fine as well:

[image: this is okay]

I could create a new table and insert the data manually for the 200 entries but there are new ones everyday, it needs to be automatic.

Thanks and have a great day

PS: Sorry for the bad title, I couldn't describe this problem in another way

Comment: That format is called JSON, there it built-in support for it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html  - However by far the best thing to do would be to configure or intercept the inserts & normalize the data to a proper table structure.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link, I will check it out.